# Build a small code-hosting server at home

Tags: hosting

This is more of an hardware question than a software one but still...:
I would like to have a server at home to play/experiment with it.
The usages would be to host my own repositories (bzr, svn, etc), have a small webserver to host a wiki/trac for my personal programming projects and a ftp to host files.

So I'm considering buying a small PC but it this ecological concerned times that we're living in I would really like to have a **small** power consumption! So any advice on what I should buy?

Thank you!

Comment: so exactly why does stackoverflow have a not-programming-related tag - tell me?

Comment: I think this is a good question... In our age of conservation, we should focus on lower power consumption.

Comment: Tags are created by the person that asked the question - the presence of a tag doesn't indicate the sanctity of the topic

Comment: Yes indeed, but how does commenting like that help?  Re-tagging the question would have been more helpful.

Comment: The history of edits to this question indicate that you had re tagged the question before Mitch Wheat made that comment - so he wouldn't have needed to retag it. Since one close vote has been made, I would guess it was made by Mitch Wheat and he was commenting to indicate why it was made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This site](http://www.mini-box.com/site/index.html) has some really low cost and low power computers, that are x86 to boot! These won't be any speed demon computers, but if you just want to use it for light home usage such as repository and ftp serving, you should be fine.

[Here](http://www.mini-box.com/Alix-3D-Board-3-LAN-1-MINI-PCI-1_3?sc=8&category=19) is a computer that runs on about 5 watts... You could run 12 on the power it takes to run a light bulb!

Answer (score 0):

May be better to use a shared service instead than a dedicated home server than will always be turn on even when not working. Sharing a server allows you to use the computacional power you need instead of wasting it on  a standby computer.

I recommend http://itrebal.com/ for setting your server.